# Javascript import: "no bare module allowed"?

Tags: javascript, import, code-documentation

I was reading this article about Javascript module:
https://javascript.info/modules-intro#no-bare-modules-allowed

It says

> In the browser, import must get either a relative or absolute URL.
> Modules without any path are called “bare” modules. Such modules are
> not allowed in import.

However, in a lot of documentations that I see, `import` is being used with "bare" module, this one for example:

https://sheet2api.com/google-sheet-javascript/

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

The example you posted is a Node.js example, it installs with the npm package manager

The documentation said "Certain environments, like Node.js or bundle tools allow bare modules" which is true

Comment: I thought so. But why these documentations never care to mention that it is for Node.js? Is Node.js so widely used that they don't think it is necessary to mention it?